# Bootstrap fixed navbar is wider then html and causes x-overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On my website https://bennetdev.de I have a fixed-top navbar which seems to be wider then my actual html tag. I think it is a problem between the navbar and my bootstrap modal but I don't know how to solve it. Due to the wider navbar a white space on the right side is shown when you visit the page, but disappears when opening the modal (through the contact button) and is not existent anymore until you refresh the page. Anyone knows how to fix this?

EDIT: There is no overflow because I hide the x-overflow on my body element but what I mean is the white bar on the right side, which would be a x-overflow without me hiding it

[image: White Bar]

Comment: Looks ok to me, no overflow or horizontal scrollbar. Checked in Chrome, IE11, Edge, Firefox, Opera.

Comment: @2pha I will add a screenshot but try refreshing a few times, doenst occur to me every time either

Comment: Ahh, yes, I see it now. It seems to be caused by the negative margins on a "row". In your case, the div `<div class="project row" >`. I added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, yes, I see it now. It seems to be caused by the negative margins on a "row".
In your case, the div `<div class="project row" >`.
For bootstrap rows and columns to work correctly (ie. negative margins), the parent of a "row" should have the class "container". See the [docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

eg.

```
<div id="projects" class="container">
  <div class="project row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-height: 210px;` to define how much height do you want for your nav bar.

Anyway I recommended to upload some code that we can see.